# Can we do big data load testing by using Java request sampler?

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, database-performance

We have created custom Hbase plugin and we are using sampler as "java request" in jmeter, here we are passing "table name", data, Zooker keeper location then we are inserting the data to Hbase then data is inserting to Hbase, Now my question is how we can update and delete the data ? by using the java request sampler?

Please advise me a solution, it will be great helpful.

Comment: Try YCSB rather than JMeter

Comment: what is this "YCSB" it is any tool ?,  pls send me a reference link.

Comment: I trust your ability to search for it